# How to check which icons are available in svg file?

Tags: css, svg

In my vuejs2/html app based on external template svg icons
are used, like :

```
<svg class="icon icon-plus">
    <use xlink:href="/img/icons.svg#plus" />
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon-basket">
    <use xlink:href="/img/icons.svg#basket" />
</svg>
```

File icons.svg has 20 KiB in size and I wonder

1. if there is a way to check which icons are available in this
   file? How can I check it? I need to of close, like ”x", but making

   icons.svg#close

I failed.

2. Can I modify color/background color of these icons? I need to modify it with css propoties and set custom colors.
3. Are there some available resource easy to use to create such svg files?

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking three distinct questions here. Please see [ask], then revise to ask just one question with enough detail for us to answer.

Comment: As SVG is a text file, most probably there is a way to search in it.

Comment: The solution I can think of is to load the SVG file as you request an XML file by Javascript (by a promise). Then you could search in it.

Comment: If you open the SVG file in a browser and look for id's with the developer tool. Something like `[...document.querySelectorAll('symbol[id]')].map(elm => elm.id).join('\n')` would list all id's for all the `<symbol>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern svg icon libraries (feather-icons, fontAwesome etc.) provide something like a **"cheat sheet"** showing all available icons.
Besides, they will most likely provide an **api for embedding and styling** (like changing icon colors).

If you can't find any documentation, you could try to create an visual overview like so:

```js
let svgIcons = document.querySelector('#svgIcons');
let symbols =  svgIcons.querySelectorAll('symbol[id]');
let symbolUseHtml = '';

symbols.forEach(function(el, i){
  let id = el.id;
  let viewBox = el.getAttribute('viewBox');
  let viewBoxAtt = viewBox ? 'viewBox="'+viewBox+'"' : '';
  symbolUseHtml +=
'<div class="icon-wrp"><svg class="icon icon-'+id+'" id="icon-'+id+'" '+viewBoxAtt+'><use href="#'+id+'"></svg><p>'+id+'</p></div>';
});
symbolUseHtml+='';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', symbolUseHtml);
```

```css
.icon-wrp{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:0.5em;
  border:1px solid #ccc
}

#icon-home{
    fill: red;
}

#icon-close{
    fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgIcons" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 34 48">
    <path d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="close" viewBox="0 0 27 48">
    <path d="M26.16,17.92l-10.44,10.44l10.44,10.44l-2.44,2.44l-10.44-10.44l-10.44,10.44l-2.44-2.44l10.44-10.44l-10.44-10.44l2.44-2.44l10.44,10.44l10.44-10.44Z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Most likely querying for `<symbol>` elements will do the trick – as @chrwahl recommended.

Unfortunately, there is no standardized concept, how icon libraries are referencing icon assets:
Some might use nested svg elements or elements wrapped in a `<def>`.
Here is a draft of a visual "icon Inspector" to illustrate the different flavors:

**Icon inspector example**

```js
let svgIcons = document.querySelector(".svgIcons");
let svgMarkup = document.querySelector("#svgMarkup");
let svgUseCode = document.querySelector("#svgUseCode");
let svgUseCodeID = document.querySelector("#svgUseCodeID");
let svgIconAssets = document.querySelector(".svgIconAssets");
let iconType = "";
let iconHtml = "";

// default example svg
let svgSrc = `<svg id="svgIcons" class="svgIcons" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 34 48">
        <path d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="close" viewBox="0 0 27 48">
        <path d="M26.16,17.92l-10.44,10.44l10.44,10.44l-2.44,2.44l-10.44-10.44l-10.44,10.44l-2.44-2.44l10.44-10.44l-10.44-10.44l2.44-2.44l10.44,10.44l10.44-10.44Z" />
      </symbol>
    </svg>`;
svgMarkup.value = svgSrc;
loadSvg(svgSrc);

let svgSrcSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".trackChange");

svgSrcSelect.forEach(function (el, i) {
  el.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    svgSrc = e.target.value;
    loadSvg(svgSrc);
  });
});

function loadSvg(src) {
  // if external src
  if (src.indexOf("<svg") == -1) {
    fetch(src)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
        // add temporary svg to DOM
        svgIcons.innerHTML = data;
        renderIcons(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      let errorData ='<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><symbol id="error" viewBox="0 0 100 100" ><text  x="50" y="50" width="100"  text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:25%; fill:red">Not available</text></symbol></svg>';
      svgIcons.innerHTML = errorData;
      renderIcons(errorData);
      })
  }
  
  // if src is svg markup
  else {
    svgIcons.innerHTML = src;
    renderIcons(src);
  }
}



function renderIcons(data) {
  let svgOuter = svgIcons.querySelector("svg");
  let nested = svgOuter.querySelectorAll("svg");
  let symbols = svgOuter.querySelectorAll("symbol");
  let icons = symbols.length ? symbols : nested;
  let nonPathEls = svgIcons.querySelectorAll("polyline, line");

  iconType = icons == symbols ? "symbols" : "nested svgs";
  iconHtml = "";

  icons.forEach(function (el, i) {
    let id = el.id ? el.id : "";
    let idAtt = id ? ' id="icon-'+id+'" ' : '';
    /**
     * if an icon doesn't have an id –
     * try to fetch the last class name
     **/
    let classAtt = !id ? el.classList : "";
    let classLast = classAtt ? [].slice.call(classAtt).pop() : "";
    let viewBox = el.getAttribute("viewBox");
    let viewBoxAtt = viewBox ? 'viewBox="' + viewBox + '"' : "";
    let iconDef = id ? document.querySelector("#" + id) : "";
    let iconAsset = iconDef ? iconDef : el;
    let iconUseHtml = "";

    /**
     * if icon defs contain other elements
     * than paths – like polyline or line –
     * maybe they're intended to have outlines/strokes
     * but no fill (like in feather-icons)
     **/
    if (iconAsset) {
      let children = iconAsset.childNodes;
      if (children.length && nonPathEls.length) {
        children.forEach(function (sub, i) {
          sub.classList.add("icon-inner-stroke");
        });
      }

      let iconInner = iconAsset ? iconAsset.innerHTML : "";
      let iconSelector = !id ? "class: " + '<strong>'+classLast+'</strong>' : "id: " + '<strong>'+id+'</strong>';

      if (id) {
        iconUseHtml =
          '<svg class="icon-use icon-use-' +
          id +
          idAtt+
          viewBoxAtt +
          ">\n" +
          '<use href="' +
          id +
          '" />\n' +
          "</svg>\n";
      }

      let dataUse = iconUseHtml
        ? 'data-use="' + encodeURIComponent(iconUseHtml) + '" '
        : 'data-use=""';

      iconHtml +=
        '<div class="icon-wrp" ' +
        dataUse +
        " >" +
        '<svg class="icon icon-' +
        id + '" '+
        idAtt+
        viewBoxAtt +
        ">" +
        iconInner +
        "</svg>" +
        '<p class="icon-label">' +
        iconSelector +
        "<br>type: " +
        iconType +
        "</p>" +
        "</div>";

      //console.log(svgIconAssets)
    }
  });
  svgIconAssets.innerHTML = iconHtml;
  let svgIconWrp = svgIconAssets.querySelectorAll(".icon-wrp");
  svgIconWrp.forEach(function (el, i) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      let currentIcon = e.target.closest(".icon-wrp");
      let iconCode = '<!-- not selectable by id -->\n'+currentIcon.innerHTML; 
      let useCode = currentIcon.getAttribute("data-use");
      useCode = useCode ? decodeURIComponent(useCode) : iconCode;
      svgUseCode.value = useCode;
      svgUseCodeID.innerHTML =
        "<strong>" + currentIcon.querySelector("svg").id + "</strong>";
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
}

:root {
  --svgHover: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.45em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #ddd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svgIconAssets {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.icon-wrp {
  width: 10vw;
  font-size: 4vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-wrp * {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #999;
  fill: #999;
  cursor:pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: var(--svgHover);
    fill: var(--svgHover);
  }
}

.icon-inner-stroke {
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: none;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

label{
  font-size:0.8rem;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom:0.25rem;
}

.svgDisplay {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.frm-wrp {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  * {
    width: 100%;
  }
  textarea {
    min-height: 5em;
    height: 90%;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
  
  input, textarea{
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="svgDisplay">
    <div class="svgIcons" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="svgIconAssets"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="frm-wrp">
    <label>Svg URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="svgSrcSelect" class="svgSrcSelect trackChange" list="dataSrc" placeholder="select example or paste svg url" />
    <datalist id="dataSrc">
      <option value="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather-sprite.svg">Feather icons</option>
      <option value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/sprites/regular.svg">FontAwesome (6.0)</option>
      <option value="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome-svg-icons@0.1.0/svg-sprite.svg">FontAwesome (0.1)</option>
    </datalist>
    <label>Svg markup</label>
    <textarea id="svgMarkup" class="svgMarkup trackChange" placeholder="enter svg code"></textarea>
    <label>Svg use code: <span id="svgUseCodeID"></span></label>
    <textarea id="svgUseCode" class="svgUseCode" placeholder="enter svg code"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example contains 3 icon library svgs (you can select them in the URL field as datalist options).
Significant differences:

**1. Feather icons**

- icons are defined as symbols
- contain different element types like circle, polyline etc. (in addition to `<path>`)
- all icons are **styled by stroke attributes** (stroke, stroke-width, stroke-linecap)

**2. FontAwesome (6.0)**

- icons are defined as symbols
- all assets are solid/closed `<path>` shapes
- all icons are **styled by fill attribute**

**3. FontAwesome (0.1)**

- icons are grouped in nested svg elements
- using class names instead of IDs
  (probably supposed to be just a test file)